# personalize each email with postfix

Tags: postfix

I looking for personalize each email with their own links to track and offer unsubscribe links and their own return-path email without using xverp, but i couldn't find a way to send a generic email to postfix and let it modify each one, something just like x-smtpapi header of sendgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a task that your MTA should be responsible for. Your application ought to generate the emails individually and submit them to postfix for delivery.